# The SSL connection could not be established. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl

While debugging this part of code, i am getting

> The SSL connection could not be established

Can anybody provide a solution?

```
            WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(URL);
            wr.Method = "DELETE";
            
            using (WebResponse objResponse = wr.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string Res = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    sr.Close();
                }
                objResponse.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Is your "URL" starting with `http` or `https` ?

Comment: @Batuhan URL starting with https

Comment: Do you have any further info from the exception? Which version of windows and .NET is running on the server and client?

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, error) => { return true; };
        using (Stream webStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        using (StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webStream, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            requestWriter.Write(data);
        }
        try
        {
            WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream() ?? Stream.Null)
            using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream))
            {
                return responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).